# Ошибка при записи в .txt

Tags: python-3.x

Программа выполняет первый цикл корректно, в файл записываются данные. Следующие повторения приводят к исключению.

```
InfoIP = [2.2, "b"]
path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\IPcheck.txt"
f = open(path, "a")
 
 
driver.get("https://web.telegram.org/z/#5024075764")
time.sleep(5)
 
def sendall():
    try:
        driver.execute_script('window.open("https://2ip.ru/")')
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        time.sleep(3)
        InfoIP[0] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d_clip_button"]/span').text
        InfoIP[1] = "-----------"
        f.write("\n" + " ".join(InfoIP))
        f.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Error2")
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        time.sleep(5)
 
while True:
    try:
        sendall()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Приводит к ошибке строка `f.write("\n" + " ".join(InfoIP))` вне зависимости от значения. Без `try`:

```
(<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError('I/O operation on closed file.'),
 <traceback object at 0x000001EAB4D9FE80>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
f = open(path, "a")
...
def sendall():
    try:
        ...
        f.write("\n" + " ".join(InfoIP))
        f.close()
```

Вы открываете файл заранее, а потом закрываете его в функции. При повторном вызове функции файл уже закрыт. Открывайте файл там же, где осуществляете запись и лучше таким образом через менеджер контекста, чтобы он закрывался автоматически:

```py
...
def sendall():
    try:
        ...
        with open(path, "a") as f:
            f.write("\n" + " ".join(InfoIP))
```